# Is it worth to compromise on speed to follow PEP 8 guidelines?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy

I have this long line of code:

```py
enc = encoder.predict(np.array([data[stock][4*i:4*(i+30)] for i in range(lens[stock]+days-30)]))
```

The problem is, the number of characters (97) exceed 79, which is not allowed by PEP 8. To follow the PEP 8 guideline I can

```py
temp = [data[stock][4*i:4*(i+30)] for i in range(lens[stock]+days-30)]
enc = encoder.predict(np.array(temp))
```

But this creates a new variable that is stored in memory, rather then just a temporary storage in the first case. I'm assuming this takes slightly more time as well. The question is, is it worth compromising on speed to follow the guidelines/improve readability?

(PS: If there is a way to break down that one line of code into multiple lines, I would like to know)

Comment: You also use 4 magical numbers which should be replaced anyway with 4 properly named constants (making the statement even longer). Also, `temp` would be a terrible variable name, I am sure you could find a more meaningful name.

Comment: My `ipython` `timeit` test of a simpler version of making an array from a list comprehension actually runs a bit faster with the `temp` variable.  The interpreter has to run the list comprehension before it is passed to `np.array` regardless.  Assigning that list object a name does not cost extra time; there's no difference in memory usage.

Comment: So that we can give you proper advice, please describe what calculation is being performed, and make that the title of the question. See [ask]. Also include the code for the `predict` function, since that could be part of your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A reasonable question to ask, maybe not for a single instance but if you end up with extremely performance-sensitive code. [Black formats the code like this](https://black.now.sh/?version=stable&state=_Td6WFoAAATm1rRGAgAhARYAAAB0L-Wj4ACeAIBdAD2IimZxl1N_WlgA5-PRwqIocXeLYTyQR6agwuTzex71SU3kwayO6z1sOQpf5xYC_zy_BAEPWDQq9-VBhNCbawwbwgzVY-ub_WvCOL7Y51f1_HUcsxUfS0NyIVb5077-A4hRXx1pNzk63cruo-5psTm9bdRM0Lmgj93i3jDfHla0AFwQIlU9VqI6AAGcAZ8BAACQsHBwscRn-wIAAAAABFla):

```
enc = encoder.predict(
    np.array(
        [
            data[stock][4 * i : 4 * (i + 30)]
            for i in range(lens[stock] + days - 30)
        ]
    )
)
```

Comment: "if you end up with extremely performance-sensitive code." Then write it in C with Python bindings, or just stand alone C++.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bad question. Fundamentally, your line of thought is a perfect example of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). Optimization on its own is not a bad thing, but

1. you should know that this line of code is the line of code that slows the program down;
2. since the line is so complex, you should know which part of this line is the slowest;
3. you should be somewhat confident that making this single-line pile of code is worth the performance gain given the significant drop in legibility and maintainability.

It's very important to profile - to measure the performance of your code, and to find bottlenecks. Without this, we as programmers are entirely blind to the actual performance characteristics of our code. Your usual priorities should be strongly biased toward making it legible and correct well before making it fast, and when you do make it fast, you need to already know where the speedups are needed to a fairly good degree of accuracy.

In short, the code that you showed is unmaintainable. It needs to be spread over many more lines than it is now, and if you think it's worth profiling - great! Measure the before and after!